# What system functions use VertexWeights?

Tags: functions, graphs-and-networks

`EdgeWeight ->` are used by a lot of functions, but I can't find any exposed usage for `VertexWeight ->`.

I'm not asking about algorithms that could benefit from having the property pre-defined, but about ready to use system functions.

Answer (score 2):

At least the following functions make use of [`VertexWeight`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexWeight.html)

- [`WeightedGraphQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedGraphQ.html) returns `True` both for edge weighted and vertex weighted graphs. Unfortunately, it provides no way to distinguish between them.  This is annoying because [it is hard to come up with a reliable way to test for edge weights only](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1061356).
- [`ClusteringTree`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClusteringTree.html) outputs a vertex-weighted graph, and [`Dendrogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dendrogram.html) uses those weights for drawing.